# Solution for error using Apache 2.2 and mod_wsgi - Deploying django and error "Forbidden - You don't have permission to access / on this server. "

Tags: django, apache, deployment, mod-wsgi, apache2.2

### Situation:

I want to deploy a django app, and the app works fine in the server without apache, but when I try to set up the django app behind apache this error is shown.

### Error Message:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at 10.184.56.52 Port 80

### Apache Version :

```
admin@fcovsopti03:/etc/httpd/conf$ /usr/sbin/httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug 18 2015 02:00:22
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:25
Server loaded:  APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.3.9, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="logs/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
admin@fcovsopti03:/etc/httpd/conf$
```

### Apache and Module mod_wsgi installation

```
$ yum install python27-mod_wsgi.x86_64
```

### Apache is working, but after adding the following lines and restarting the apache service the error is shown

**httpd.conf - adding configuration directives for django using mod_wsgi :**

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /u05/admin/NPortalWeb/src/TI/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /u05/admin/NPortalWeb/src/TI:/u05/admin/NPortalWeb/site-packages

<Directory /u05/admin/NPortalWeb/src/>
<Files wsgi.py>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
```

### Users and Groups

```
root@fcovsopti03:/etc/httpd/conf# id apache
uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache),903(admin)
root@fcovsopti03:/etc/httpd/conf# id admin
uid=903(admin) gid=903(admin) groups=903(admin),48(apache)
```

### Directory permissions

```
admin@fcovsopti03:/u05/admin/NPortalWeb/src$ ll
total 148
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 admin admin 131072 Sep 24 16:45 db.sqlite3
drwxr-xr-x. 4 admin admin   4096 Sep 30 14:52 DisponibilidadTI
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 admin admin    245 Sep 24 16:45 manage.py
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 admin admin   3446 Sep 30 14:53 nohup.out
drwxr-xr-x. 2 admin admin   4096 Sep 30 14:52 TI
admin@fcovsopti03:/u05/admin/NPortalWeb/src$
```

### Linux Version:

```
admin@fcovsopti03:/u05/admin/NPortalWeb/src$ lsb_release -i -r
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Release:    6.5
```

**Thank you for any suggestion or idea.**

Comment: Hi, not sure, but a way to investigate : could be a *SELinux* problem ...  


Check `ls -lhZ` and `restorecon -r <path_of_your_httpd_conf_files>`